# Time complexity of Prune and Search

Tags: algorithm, pruning

I read a lot of stuff about Prune and Search algorithm and I even asked some of it for confirmation.

[This](http://par.cse.nsysu.edu.tw/~cbyang/course/algo/algonote/algo6.ppt) is a great source. However, some things are hard for me to understand. Like the time complexity of Prune and Search:

[image]

Can someone provide a brief explanation for this?

Comment: This is the time complexity of a particular prune and search type algorithm. You should describe the algorithm and what you don't understand in this computation.

Comment: @hivert It's probably the median-of-medians algorithm.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Yes, the one that finds the median. It's kinda confusing.

Answer (score 0):

They're solving the recurrence T(n) <= T(n/5) + T(3n/4) + Cn (C is the big-O constant) via some bizarre method that I don't recognize. Modulo the missing base case and floor and ceiling operators, we can solve it via [Akra–Bazzi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra-Bazzi_method) or the substitution method (this answer).

The inductive hypothesis is that T(n') <= 20Cn' for all n' < n. Then

```
T(n) <= T(n/5) + T(3n/4) + Cn
     <= 20C(n/5) + 20C(3n/4) + Cn
      = 20C(4n/20) + 20C(15n/20) + Cn
      = 4Cn + 15Cn + Cn
      = 20Cn.
```